# How to use anchor links to scroll within a div without scrolling the main page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am trying to use links to scroll the content within a `div`.
HTML is here:

```
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="/img/header.jpg" alt="Ace Land Surveying"></a>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Types of Surveys</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Request a Survey</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Past Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="last">SOQ</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="column left">
      <ul class="survey-type-list">
        <li><h2><a href="#type1">CLICK HERE</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#type2">CLICK HERE</a></h2></li>
        <li><h2><a href="#type3">CLICK HERE</a></h2></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="column right" id="survey-column">
      <div class="survey-type" id="type1">
        <p> ... long text ... </p>
      </div>
      <div class="survey-type" id="type2">
        <p> ... long text ... </p>
      </div>
      <div class="survey-type" id="type3">
        <p> ... long text ... </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="footer-top">
    <div class="wrapper"></div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

and the CSS:

```
header {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #02274b;
}

.column {
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), transparent);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), transparent);
}

.column.left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.column.right {
  float: right;
  width: 60%;
}

.survey-type-list li {
  margin: 0 0 4px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.survey-type-list h2 {
  font-size: 13px;
}

#survey-column {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 460px;
}

.survey-type {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 460px;
}
```

The problem is that the entire page moves with the content inside the `div`.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q8a1s5wj/8/

I tried several other threads here but none could solve my problem.

How can I prevent the whole page from scrolling and just scroll inside the right column with my anchor links?

I want to be able to click the link in the left column and see the right column scroll but not the move the entire page.

Comment: you can use JQuery Libraries, use scrollTop function :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xo4ocjjg/)

Some minor adaptations to the CSS - not doing this gave the wrong element offset :

```
#survey-column {
  position: relative;
}
```

This one's just so the last `div` can scroll to the top completely :

```
.survey-type {
  height: 520px;
}
```

And a bit of script to make it work :

```
$(function() {

$('.column.left a').click(function() {

    var goal = $(this.hash).position().top-20,
    aim = goal+$('#survey-column').scrollTop();

    $('#survey-column').scrollTop(aim);

    return false;
});
});
```

The 20 pixels deduction of `goal` is just done to keep the same top padding as was started with...

Comment: This solution works perfectly. The js was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can add position as fixed on top div element, i have checked your code on jsfiddle and added position style attribute in wrapper div element

```
<div class="wrapper" style="position:fixed; margin-top:10px">
```

Answer (score -1):

just add this

```
.stop-scrolling {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

this class to your body tag.

Reference: [How to disable scrolling temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q8a1s5wj/2/

Comment: Thanks for the great response. Unfortunately this didn't work. It's my fault though I failed to recreate my problem accurately in the fiddle. You can see my problem here (http://fullclinch.com/survey-types.php) I will also re-write my question and code in my OP